# Passing a List to another class

Tags: c#, list

I know some codes here are not clear. I'm still in the process of trying out things. I've got three questions, why does an error shows up when adding a string in my list? How do I pass the List in Class1 to my main class? And is my syntax correct in List passArr? Not sure if I should add parenthesis at the end of passArr.

```
class Class1
{
    public static List<string> passArr
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static void passIt()
    {
        passArr.Add("A"); //Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1.passIt();
        List<string> passArr1 = Class1.passArr;
        foreach (string s in passArr1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're never *creating* a list, so the `passArr` property (which needs renaming, by the way) always has a value of `null`. You need something like:

```
Class1.passArr = new List<string>();
```

at some point. Another alternative would be to make it a read-only property backed by a field with an initializer:

```
private static readonly List<string> passArr = new List<string>();
public static List<string> PassArr { get { return passArr; } }
```

(This complies with naming convention in terms of *case*, but it's still not a meaningful name, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I tried changing my List<string> passArr1 = Class1.passArr to your answer, an error occured that says Class1 does not contain a definition for 'passArr1'.

Comment: you want Class1.PassArr, your passArr is now a private list with a getter

Comment: Sorry, I changed the wrong code. However, when I tried implementing Jon Skeet's fix, the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." still showed up.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/aWhfu8UM What is wrong with my code, if you can assist please.

Comment: @Si8: That's not the way the site works. If you have a different question, post it separately.

Comment: Thanks for response. I was able to figure it out . I had to instantiate the list first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jon Skeet and Sayse for the answers. It's all now clear to me, the real problem is I'm trying to add something in the list (using passIt method) without creating a new object for the list.

Here's my new code:

Main Class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 cs = new Class1();
        cs.passIt();
        foreach (string s in cs.passArr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside main: " + s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Class1

```
class Class1
{
    public List<string> passArr
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void passIt()
    {
        passArr = new List<string>();
        passArr.Add("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize this is an OLD question. But for the beginner programmer, try instantiating the list in a constructor: `public Class1() { passArr = new List<string>(); }`